# Can the Naruto manga be ordered in India?

Tags: naruto, india

Can we order the *Naruto* manga in India? I am a big fan of *Naruto* but Animax stopped it. I am watching the series on YouTube, but I also want to read the manga.

Comment: You can read the manga through Crunchyroll, however, as your answer says "order" and not just "read", I'll just keep this as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

One site you can use is [Amazon.In](http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_0_10?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=naruto+vol+1&sprefix=naruto+vol+1%2Caps%2C115&rh=n%3A976389031%2Ck%3Anaruto+vol+1), although I'm not sure of the range of Naruto volumes they seem to have most of them for about ₹299.00 each.

These are in English rather than Hindi.

Comment: I don't think we can even expect Hindi version.

Answer (score 2):

Besides Amazon mentioned in Toshinou Kyouko's answer, Naruto volumes are also available online on [Flipkart](https://www.flipkart.com/books/fiction-nonfiction-books/pr?sid=bks,fnf&q=Naruto&otracker=categorytree), [Snapdeal](https://www.snapdeal.com/search?keyword=Naruto&categoryId=364&sort=rlvncy), [Sapna Online](https://www.sapnaonline.com/general-search?searchkey=Naruto).

Naruto volumes are also available at a few (offline) bookstores, but this is mostly limited to the major Indian cities. I have seen Naruto volumes on sale at two locations of [Landmark Stores](http://www.landmarkonthenet.com/page/store-locator/) when I <s>teleported there</s> visited them. I expect to see them at their other store locations, and maybe also at some other large bookstores.

Buying from offline bookstores will offer you a few benefits.

- Get a look and feel before buying them.
- Bargain for a better discount, especially if ordering multiple volumes.
- Place a custom order for any missing volumes.

---

*Manga volumes on sale at Landmark, [Forum Mall](http://www.theforumexperience.com/), Koramangala Bengaluru*

[image: Naruto volumes on sale at Landmark, Koramangala, Bengaluru]
[image: Manga volumes on sale at Landmark, Koramangala, Bengaluru]

*Manga volumes on sale at Landmark, [Orion Mall](http://orionmalls.com/#/Orion%20Mall%20at%20Brigade%20Gateway), Malleshwaram Bengaluru*

[image: Manga volumes on sale at Landmark, Malleshwaram, Bengaluru]

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers, there is also the Comic Con India, where you can procure different types of anime merchandise including Manga Volumes.

Going from personal experience, you can purchase multiple volumes for "good" discounts/offers at such conventions (Though most popular volumes may be sold out). They also allow you to place order, which will be later shipped to the given address.

Typically these happen once a year in cities such as Delhi, Mumbai, Hyderabad and Bangalore.

Check out below for more details and events.
http://comicconindia.com/#